# Doctrine - conditional where

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I have this method in my Laravel controller :

```
public function getUserOrders($userId) :array{    
    $results = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('Orders.orderItemCount')
        ->from($this->entityClass, 'Orders')
        ->Where("Orders.orderItemCount > '0'")
        ->andWhere("Orders.orderTotalPrice > '0'")
        ->andWhere("Orders.usersUserId = '{$userId}'")
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    return $results;
}
```

I want to change this method that $userId will be optional , so  last condition is not require in this situation:

```
public function getUserOrders($userId = NULL) :array{    
    $results = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('Orders.orderItemCount')
        ->from($this->entityClass, 'Orders')
        ->Where("Orders.orderItemCount > '0'")
        ->andWhere("Orders.orderTotalPrice > '0'")
        if (!is_null($userId))
           ->andWhere("Orders.usersUserId = '{$userId}'")
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    return $results;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to achieve this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
public function getUserOrders($userId = NULL) :array{    
$results = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('Orders.orderItemCount')
    ->from($this->entityClass, 'Orders')
    ->Where("Orders.orderItemCount > '0'")
    ->andWhere("Orders.orderTotalPrice > '0'");
    if (!is_null($userId)){
       $results->andWhere("Orders.usersUserId" = $userId);
    }
    $results->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

return $results;
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: Look at your code. You've got a semicolon on `->andWhere("Orders.orderTotalPrice > '0'");`. Even if you remove the semicolon, it won't work, either. There's more to do here.

Comment: is okk i forget to write $results-> in if condition now it is right and no issue by semicolon

Comment: getUserOrders() must be of the type array, object returned

Comment: please check dd($results);